# How many words of length W can be made using an alphabet with L letters.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was trying with L choose W, but then I don't know if that is enough.

Comment: You don't know if L choose W is the answer? What small values of L and W did you test that formula on? If, say, you tried setting L = W = 2, what value did you compute for 2 choose 2, and how many words of length 2 did you find using a two-letter alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

If the **letters are reusable** then 
Total words = $L^w$ (i.e $L*L*L*... W times$)

If the **letters are not reusable**
Total words = $L(L-1)(L-2)(L-3) ........(L-W+1)$  i.e $^Lp_w$ (W permutation of L distinct things)

You could refer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have L spaces to fill.  You have W choices for each of the L spaces.

So that's $W \cdot W \cdot \dots W$ L times; that is, $W^L$.